# How to present enum table property in Laravel Model

Tags: php, database, laravel, enums

I have a table which has a enum property, and I'm wondering how to present it in a Model class.

Actually, I'm building a Model class, for which I will create migrations simultaneously, and that migration than needs to create a table with enum property. So how to present that enum in Model since PHP doesn't have enum.
I mean I don't exactly know how Laravel works (have just started with it), but I think you get me.

I've just heard some advice such as an enum being a great property to use, but I'll use it anyway. The database tables are preconditioned so I have to do it like that.

So how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my use case I need enum field for store gender and I use first character of each. following is way to create enum field inside migration.

```
$table->enum('gender', ['m', 'f']);
```

And whenever I want to store it in database I changed the value like below.

```
$input['gender'] = strtolower($input['gender']) == 'male') ? 'm' : 'f';
```

You need to small function before storing model.